# Trigger en MySQL para notas

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Hola amigos no se si me puedan ayudar nunca habia hecho esto, necesito crear un procedimiento almacenado que en el momento que se inserte un dato en mi BD este cambie un . por una , es decir si ingrese una nota de 4.7 quiero que en mysql se inserte el dato y luego haga un update automaticamente para pasar ese . a una ,
Hasta el momento tengo este codigo pero no logro hacerlo funcionar me da un error de sintaxis

```
CREATE TRIGGER `actualizarNota` before UPDATE ON `grades_validation` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF old.grade = new.grade 
    THEN
       UPDATE `grades_validation` SET grade = Replace(grade,".",",");
  END IF ;
END
```

Comment: Agrega que has intentado

Comment: A ver si entendí, el usuario escribe esto: `4.7` y quieres un procedimiento para que se cambie a esto `4,7`. ¿Entendí bien? Si es sí, ¿por qué querrías hacer eso? ¿De qué tipo es la columna donde se guardará ese dato?

Comment: Es un varchar es una nota, resulta que ese dato entra con un . y necesito remplazar ese . por una , necesito hacerlo por que ese dato va hacia otra base de datos que es oracle pero ese campo no recibe ,

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER `actualizarNota` before UPDATE ON `grades_validation` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF old.grade = new.grade 
    THEN
       UPDATE `grades_validation` SET grade = Replace(grade,".",",")
  END IF ;
END Este es mi codigo hasta el momento pero no logro hacerlo funcionar.

Comment: Eso no es un procedimiento si no un trigger

Comment: Ay perdon tienes toda la razón no se ni que estaba pensando me confundi; (UPDATE grades_validation SET grade = Replace(grade,".",",") se que esta sentiencia esta bien, pero realmente no se por que me falla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya encontre la respuesta por si alguien le sirve.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `actualizarNota` BEFORE INSERT ON `grades_validation` FOR EACH ROW SET new.grade = Replace(new.grade,".",",")
```